# How to fork shell to foreground instead of background?

Tags: shell, jobs, dash-shell

I want to use a shell script to check if it is interactive. If so, it should spawn a `fish` and continue the rest of the script in the background. Otherwise, it should not run `fish` and continue running the rest of the script.

How I check if the shell is interactive:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $- in
    *i*) echo "interactive" ;;
    *) echo "non-interactive" ;;
esac
```

Now, I want to spawn a different shell in the *foreground* if it is interactive, and continue to run the rest of the script in the background.

In this example, it will wait until I exit `fish` to run `echo "continue...`.

```
#!/bin/sh

case $- in
    *i*) fish ;;
    *) ;;
esac

echo "continue..."
```

Things I tried:

- If I use `fish &`, the rest of the script runs in the foreground and `fish` runs in the background.
- If I use `fish`, the script runs fish in the foreground, but only continues the rest of the script once the `fish` shell is exits.
- If I use `exec fish`, the script runs fish in the foreground, but does not run the rest of the script, because `fish` replaces the parent.

Note that I am using `dash` and *not* `bash` for the script, so it should not contain any bashisms.

Comment: You have to just change the order. Just put the `echo continue...` before `fish` and add a `&`.

Comment: @KamilCuk in my scenario, `echo "continue..."` represents a command that must be executed *after* the `case` test.

Comment: You want to use `&` so it will run in the background so it will run _simultaneously_ (in any order). If you wan t to execute it _after_ the case test, place it before case test. It doesn't work that way, you cannot schedule a background job to run after something. You can synchronize using sleep `( sleep 5; echo continue; ) & case ....` which is the worst way to synchronize.